# Why does the class ArrayDeque not extend from AbstractQueue?

Tags: java, collections, arraydeque

Why is the class ArrayDeque defined as

```
public class ArrayDeque<E> extends AbstractCollection<E>
                       implements Deque<E>, Cloneable, Serializable
```

and not as

```
public class ArrayDeque<E> extends AbstractQueue<E>
                       implements Deque<E>, Cloneable, Serializable
```

If you look at the following diagram (which has errors, the relation of ArrayDeque to Set is completely wrong) it would make sense that ArrayDeque would inherit from AbstractQueue since it implements the Queue interface indirectly trough the Deque interface.

[image]
<sub>(source: [academic.ru](http://en.academic.ru/pictures/enwiki/67/Collection_Classes.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Why you  want to know? Your question is legitimate, but it's an internal decision and shouldn't really concern you :)

Comment: Go through the source for `ArrayDeque`, `AbstractQueue` and `AbstractCollection` and try to find the answer to this mystery?

Comment: I was going to guess it was because ArrayDeque predated AbstractQueue, but it doesn't. ArrayDeque is from Java 6, while AbstractQueue is from Java 5.

Answer (score 2):

One of the jsr166 maintainers posted on the [OpenJDK core-libs](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2014-February/025048.html):

> I don't think of ArrayDeque as a queue/deque at all.  We just have two
>   fundamental data structures here (ArrayList (ordinary resizable array) and
>   ArrayDeque (circular resizable array)) both of which can implement List and
>   Queue in reasonable ways, and ArrayDeque can additionally implement Deque.

Extending AbstractCollection and implementing Deque is consistent with that view.

It also is a conservative move because [it would allow future versions of ArrayDeque to extend AbstractList](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8143850) to implement most of List interface.  This would only happen if it is considered legal and or [desirable to implement both List and Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) due to conflicting equals/hashCode contracts.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayDeque can be used as double ended queue, stack, and linked list. I think its more of a design decision. Here, in ArrayDeque, we need to be more specific while adding/removing elements. For eg.

```
[ArrayDeque.java]
    public boolean add(E e) {
        addLast(e);
        return true;
    }
[AbstractQueue.java]
public boolean add(E e) {
        if (offer(e))
            return true;
        else
            throw new IllegalStateException("Queue full");
    }
```

Since deque is double ended, we need to be specific where we are adding the element.

Another design consideration could be to reduce the call stack. If you inherit AbstractQueue, it will increase the function call stack with no extra benefit.

Eg.,

Now,

add() -> addLast()

If it inherits AbstractQueue,

add() -> offer() -> offerLast() -> addLast()

Also, by not inheriting AbstractQueue, we are able to reuse small chunks of add, remove operations for different data structures(Queue, Stack, and Linked List) implemented in ArrayDeque.

Finally, Joshua Bloch (author of this API) knows better :)